# How to resolve PyCaret error : No matching distribution found for sktime~=0.11.4

Tags: pip, pycaret

I am receiving following error while I am trying to deploy app based on streamlit in heroku.

```
ERROR: No matching distribution found for sktime~=0.11.4
```

I have referred various forums but could not find a solution.

PyCaret version I have is `pycaret==3.0.0rc3`.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to install `sktime~=0.11.4`. The `~=` notation means that `pip` will try to install the latest `0.11.*` version of `sktime`. At the time of your question (and also at the time of this answer), the latest version available matching `0.11.*` is `0.11.4`.

This version is only available for "Python >=3.7, <3.10". See on the [sktime Pypi page](https://pypi.org/project/sktime/0.11.4/):

[image: Python >=3.7, <3.10]

If you wish to keep using Python 3.10, you can install `sktime>=0.13.0`, `0.13.0` being the first version available to Python 3.10.

Otherwise, you will need to downgrade your version of Python.